# OBIEE 11g installation stuck

Tags: oracle, obiee

I am new to OBI. I was trying to install OBIEE 11g Oracle Business Intelligence, v. 11.1.1.9.0. But when my installation reached to step 13 of 14, **Deploying Financial Reporting JEE Application**. It seems that the installation is stuck.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Install it on what OS exactly?

Comment: Windows 8.1 pro

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to install OBIEE on Server OS (Windows 2012, Linux etc) and not desktop OS (Windows 7/10 etc).

Answer (score 0):

Installing a whole farm of servers - which is what OBI is - on  a Windows DESKTOP operating system never was, is not and will never bea good idea!

https://dimensionality.ch/2017/05/06/installing-oracle-bi-on-windows-7-8-10/